# What is the best approach to Query one Table with a combo box in MS Access containing multiple search options?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, vba

I'm new to this so don't be to hard on me. What i'm doing is writing an IF Else statement so for Ex.

```
    If Combo36.Value = "Contains" Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Test", , "", "[LastName] LIKE" + Contains + "", acNormal
    ElseIf Combo36.Value = "Is" Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Test", , "", "[LastName] =" + Matches + "", acNormal
    ElseIf Combo36.Value = "Begins With" Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Test", , "", "[LastName] LIKE" + BeginsWith + "", acNormal
    ElseIf Combo36.Value = "Ends With" Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Test", , "", "[LastName] LIKE" + EndsWith + "", acNormal
    ElseIf Combo36.Value = "Is Not" Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Test", , "", "[LastName] <>" + Matches + "", acNormal
```

I have combo box and textbox for fname, lname, and code. What is the best approach for something like this? How can I prevent it from returning data if both criterias arent met(Search John Evans) In database John is there but not John Evans. I know I can write a bunch of IF statements like

```
    "DoCmd.OpenForm "Test", , "", "([FirstName] LIKE" + Contains1 + "And" + "[LastName] Like" + Contains + ")" + "", acNormal",
```

but like I said I'm new to this so is there a more efficient approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured out the best approach opposed to writing a lot of if statements. I created three functions for each value field. Inside the functions I have

1st Function

```
Function valueInputFN(value As String) As String
If Forms![Searches]![Combo38] = "Is" Then
valueInputFN = ""

ElseIf Forms![Searches]![Combo38] = "Begins With" Then

ElseIf Forms![Searches]![Combo38] = "Contains" Then
valueInputFN = "*"

ElseIf Forms![Searches]![Combo38] = "Ends With" Then
valueInputFN = "*"
End If


End Function

 2nd Function
Function FirstNameFunc(Name1 As String) As String

If IsNull(Forms![Searches]![Text40].value) Then
 FirstNameFunc = "*"
 ElseIf Forms![Searches]![Text40].value = "" Then
 FirstNameFunc = "*"
Else
Forms![Searches]![Text40].SetFocus
 FirstNameFunc = Forms![Searches]![Text40].Text

 End If



End Function
3rd Function 
Function valueInput1FN(value As String) As String
If Forms![Searches]![Combo38] = "Is" Then
valueInput1FN = ""
End If
If Forms![Searches]![Combo38] = "Ends With" Then
valueInput1FN = ""
End If
If Forms![Searches]![Combo38] = "Contains" Then
valueInput1FN = "*"
End If
If Forms![Searches]![Combo38] = "Begins With" Then
valueInput1FN = "*"
End If    

End Function
```

Above is the three functions and below is what I have in the query critera.

```
Like valueInputFN("«value»") & FirstNameFunc("«Name1»") & valueInput1FN("«value»") Or "" Or Is Null
```

This works Like a charm! Now user can select Is or Begins With or Contains or Ends with and the correct data will be retrieved. I'm sure there may have been a better approach but this worked perfect for me.